# Understanding Schemas and Queries

Tags: sql

I have the following schema

```
Persons (SSN, Name, HouseId, ApartmentNumber, Salary)    
Houses (HouseID, HouseAddress, ApartmentCount, Color)  
Landlords (LandlordID, OwnerSSN, LandlordAddress)  
Ownerships (LandlordID, HouseID, PurchaseDate, PropertyTax)  
Tenants (HouseID, ApartmentNumber, LeaseTenantSSN, LeaseStartDate,   LeaseExpirationDate,  
 Rent, LastRentPaidDate, RentOverdue)
```

Find the names of all persons who lease an apartment whose rent is higher than half of that person’s salary.
I am having a rough time with the English. Does it mean I have to find all people who are landlords and tenants and what they pay for rent is greater than half their salary?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt! (Homework?)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a simple query:

```
select t.leaseTenantSSN from Tenants t join Person p on
 t.LeaseTenantSSN=p.SSN where t.Rent > p.Salary*.5;
```

Comment: why can't I use houseid instead?

Comment: Salary is in Persons table, Rent is in Tenants table. There is a relation between these two tables which does not involve houseId. That is why you don't need house id for the requirement stated in the question.

Comment: Is a lease tenant a landlord?

Comment: lease is the contract under which tenant pays rent to the landlord for right to use the house

Comment: So when I say , I am going to lease this apartment, does it mean I am going to rent it under contract?

Comment: Yes, renting is generally through a lease, which is a term based contract (6month, year, 5years etc). You could rent for shorter duration as well which may not have a lease contract in place, eg, through AirBnB.